# Nightwatch.js - Run shell script when tasks complete

Tags: automated-tests, web-deployment, nightwatch.js

With nightwatch.js is it possible to run other commands if all of my test pass?

I would like to be able to type a command that runs:

- nightwatch
- if tests pass shell script that updates repo to latest version

Actually could I use gulp to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yeah I think we used gulp - I think gulp plumber helped.